# Python parse output from Java Double.toHexString(double)

Tags: java, python

is there a possibility to parse in Python a string that was written from a Java Double.toHexString method?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString(double)

The output looks like this: '0x1.16d6b97e718ffp8'
... not sure, whether this is a standardized format.

I would expect something like

```
value=float('0x1.16d6b97e718ffp8')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'd be [`float.fromhex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex):

```
>>> float.fromhex('0x1.16d6b97e718ffp8')
278.8387679126026
```

From the docs:

> This syntax is similar to the syntax specified in section 6.4.4.2 of the C99 standard, and also to the syntax used in Java 1.5 onwards. In particular, the output of `float.hex()` is usable as a hexadecimal floating-point literal in C or Java code, and hexadecimal strings produced by C’s `%a` format character or Java’s `Double.toHexString` are accepted by `float.fromhex()`.